tsc wrongly infers an extra .default wrapper when default-importing a package
I'm trying to import jsbi@3.2.5 into my ESM project, but tsc suggests an extra .default wrapper around the default-imported package jsbi, which turns out to be incorrect at runtime.
import JSBI from 'jsbi';

// error: TS2339: Property 'BigInt' does not exist on type
// However this works as expected at runtime
console.log(JSBI.BigInt(1))

// This is what tsc suggests instead, but is actually 'undefined' at runtime
console.log(JSBI.default.BigInt(1))


I tried to look into the published jsbi package and couldn't identity the culprit.
I tried to switch moduleResolution to bundler and it works, but I can't figure what causes Node16/NodeNext resolution to go wrong.

Could someone help me identify the root cause here? Thank you!
Here are some related files.
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "issue-import-jsbi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "jsbi": "3.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }
}

jsbi/package.json
{
  "name": "jsbi",
  "version": "3.2.5",
  "repository": "GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi",
  "main": "dist/jsbi-cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/jsbi.mjs",
  "browser": "dist/jsbi-umd.js",
  "types": "jsbi.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "jsbi.d.ts"
  ],
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  ...
}

jsbi/jsbi.d.ts
export default class JSBI {
  static BigInt(from: number|string|boolean|object): JSBI;
  ...
}


Looks like jsbi 3.2.5 ships with misconfigured type declarations. In jsbi.d.ts, it declares an ESM default export with export default class JSBI, but the main entry point (dist/jsbi-cjs.js) uses module.exports = JSBI. The type declaration misleads TypeScript, making it think that an extra .default property is required.
For more information, see:

Issue #96 in the jsbi GitHub
Modules - ESM/CJS Interoperability in the TypeScript documentation
Incorrect default export in the arethetypeswrong GitHub

This issue is still present in the jsbi 4.3.0, the latest version at the time of writing.
One temporary workaround that comes to mind is adding a custom type declaration to your project to override the faulty one. For example, an index.d.ts with the following content seemed to work for me:
import JSBI from "jsbi";

declare module "jsbi" {
  export = JSBI;
}

